# Issue on iPad 2 simulator with Tableview Graphics affecting only non-retina display

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad

I have an issue with the top left tableview graphics not displaying properly only on the iPad 2 simulator. Both the iPad Retina and iPhone displays all render the image properly in bounds of the tableview's top bar. Essentially, I am updating an iPhone app on iOS 7 to a universal app supporting iOS 7 as well. And it only displays the image outside of the tableview's top bar on the non-retina display in the iPad 2 simulator.

Incorrect:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n35fv.png

Correct: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kO98.png

Comment: it would help if you posted some of the code that shows what you are doing to create this issue

Comment: Thanks for asking. I posted the answer to my own question below.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops! I found out the issue. I was using XIB's to set the size and xcasset's to load the images, and the 1x image was the same dimensions of the 2x image, so it was oversizing the image when compiled. So the non-retina display was four times as large as the needed dimensions.